# matlab filter questions

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have an array of data, it is in time domain. Each data stands for the magnitude, and that data is sampled in a frequency of 10,000Hz.
I want to do a band pass filter between two frequencies  `f1`, and `f2`. I think I need to do a low pass filter and a high pass filter. The signal does an FFT then goes through the two filters then do an inverse FFT.
My questions: is there an easy way to do the low pass and high pass filter? I don't know how to derive the transfer function based on the two cut off frequencies.

Does anyone know how?

Thanks

Comment: In order to get a realistic, fully specified filter of reasonable quality, you might also want to spec stop-band attenuation(s), pass-band ripple, and transition widths.  Whatever you do, don't just zero some bins of the FFT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on Tristan's answer, here is some Octave Code which might or might not be Matlab compatible.  The butter function derives the transfer function coefficients for you. [image].[image]

```
hz = 8000;
x = [1:1:hz*10];
t = x./hz;
pi = 3.1415;

% Create signal with 10 hz, 200 hz and 500 hz components
raw_signal = sin(10*2*pi*t)+sin(200*2*pi*t)+sin(500*2*pi*t);

% View Raw Signal Over .1 Second Window
plot(t, raw_signal)
title('Raw Signal with 10Hz, 200Hz, 500Hz Components')
xlabel('Time (Sec)')
ylabel('Amplitude')
set(gca,'XLim', [5, 5.1]);

% Create Band Pass Butterworth Filter
[S_numer, S_denom] = butter(5, [100/hz 350/hz]);
band_passed_signal = filter(S_numer, S_denom, raw_signal);

% View Band Pass Filtered Signal Over .1 Second Window
plot(t, band_passed_signal)
title('Band Pass Filtered Signal')
xlabel('Time (Sec)')
ylabel('Amplitude')
set(gca,'XLim', [5, 5.1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

MATLAB has tools that will do filtering so you don't need to do the FFT-IFFT thing yourself (which can lead to some problems).  Try using a combination of `butter` and `filter` to do what you want to do.

[Butter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/butter.html)

[Filter](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/filter.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you have signal processing toolbox I suggest you design your filter using the `sptool`, its a GUI tool for filter design that also shows you the amplitude and phase response etc. What you wan't is a bandpass filter. It can also be constructed from a lowpass and highpass filter as you suggest, but Matlab can also give you the bandpass filter directly.

If you don't have the toolbox I suggest you refer to [The Scientist and Engineer's Guide to Digital Signal Processing](http://www.dspguide.com/pdfbook.htm), the whole book is available online and has lots of good example code in Basic, which is easy to translate to Matlab. e.g [Designing bandpass windowed sinc filter](http://www.dspguide.com/ch16/4.htm).

Comment: Signal processing in basic??  Why would anybody want to do that?

Comment: Obviously you wouldn't use the Basic code in real applications, but  as the book puts it: " *learning* DSP has very different requirements than *using* DSP". So Basic in this case serves more as a pseudocode that can be easily translated to any language.

Comment: @NathanFellman : Basic was the programming language common to all personal computers going on 3 decades ago.  So it was a historical lingua franca after Fortran, but before C became more common.  And "real" DSP assembly language was usually extremely non-portable.